# How to randomly select positions to generate lists of unique numbers that are constrained to ranges

Tags: python, algorithm

Preface: Hi everyone, I've posted my problem a couple weeks ago but I failed to describe it accurately (thank you again to everyone who helped), this time I've provided a pyfiddle to show what the general desired output is and hopefully I'm better at explaining this.

**Problem:** I have 50 items, where each item has 6 positions, I need to choose 6 unique positions for each item in this list (all positions different for all items) within a range of positions 1-300

**Constraints:** For each item, each of its 6 positions must fall within a list of fixed ranges (called runs), but not be within the same run,

e.g. The runs are: `[(1,36), (37,73), (74,110), (111,148), (149,186), (187,225), (226,262), (263, 300)]`. So item 1 can have position 1, 38, 158, 198, 238, 271 - so not within the same run twice.

The positions chosen should be random - or as random as possible (see code).

**My Attempt**: My method of doing this is as such:

For each item 1-50, for each of the positions (6 positions):

- Get a list of available positions - not a used one and not one within the same run as one of the already decided 6 positions.
- randomly select a value within the list
- remove the item from the list of available runs (for choosing the other 5 positions) and add it to the list of used positions

Pyfiddle: 
https://pyfiddle.io/fiddle/2f9d05ca-ae16-46c7-9293-40fad686e7fa/?i=true

The fiddle will currently spit out a list of 48-50 list items with 6 unique positions, printing out the remaining available positions after it ultimately fails.

Unfortunately, my algorithm will almost always result in 49 (sometimes 48 and rarely it actually works at 50) item sets and will crash at the 50th as the final list will have repeated elements from the same run. I believe this is due to the fact that the runs are different sizes, so my algorithm itself is wrong. I've racked my brain for weeks trying to figure out how to do this with a different approach but have not been able to think of one. This is currently a manual process, and I could keep doing it like this but I refuse to believe there isn't an algorithm to do this! I would greatly appreciate any advice to correctly do this or as to where I went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution to prevent *hanging* of this is to choose the value only from the `run` that is used least.

We keep track of the chosen values in `seen` variable, which is set. Then each iteration from the 50 items, we shuffle the `runs` list, sort it by runs that are used least (we use `seen` set for this) and check if all the 6 runs are valid.

Then we add 6 correct values for the items.

```
runs = [(1,36), (37,73), (74,110), (111,148), (149,186), (187,225), (226,262), (263, 300)]

from random import randint, shuffle

rv, seen = [], set()
for i in range(50):
    while True:
        shuffle(runs)
        r = sorted(runs, key=lambda k: -len(set(range(k[0], k[1]+1)).difference(seen))  )[:6]
        if all(set(range(x, y+1)).difference(seen) for x, y in r):
            break
    rv.append([])
    for x, y in r:
        while True:
            i = randint(x, y+1)
            if i not in seen:
                seen.add(i)
                rv[-1].append(i)
                break

for i, row in enumerate(rv, 1):
    print(i, *row)

# assert that we have 300 unique values:
assert len(set(d for row in rv for d in row)) == 300
```

Possible output:

```
1 199 126 292 173 236 64
2 198 80 169 129 298 20
3 188 263 76 131 72 288
4 171 251 224 140 9 49
5 237 201 82 164 37 128
6 90 12 172 253 210 280
7 287 134 230 219 66 97
8 178 2 74 203 290 63
9 228 157 13 147 226 107
10 33 200 54 156 143 283

... and so on.
```

Comment: "choose the value only from the run that is used least." Wow, thank you! How did I not think of this! Now to figure out how to constrain the choices so that the average position is around 150 haha. Definitely answered my question, thanks again